# rails - vuejs(axios) - cannot print JSON response from localhost to console

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I created a simple back-end API (using rails) and I want to integrate it in my front-end (using nuxt and axios in vue.js)

In my front-end, the code is something like this

```js
async fetchArticles() {
  const response = await  this.$axios.$get('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/articles');
                console.log(response);
  return response;
 }
```

and i use the back-end like this (with json serializer in rails) :

```
class Api::V1::ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /articles
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
    render json: @articles
  end
end
```

when I try to run in postman, i was able to deliver JSON file like this

[image]

but the console can't seem to print anything. However, if I hit API from another open API sources, the API response seems to be appear in my console

I suspect there's something wrong with the rails code but I don't know what is it. Can anyone help me? Thanks

**UPDATED**

It seems I have a problem when setting up axios. It now shows an error report in console like this

[image]

How to solve it?

Comment: I don't think axios has a `$get` method. Is that a typo?

Comment: Did you try to reach `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/articles` in your browser?

Comment: `console.log(response)` does not print? can you test your console? do you filter the console messages based on warning, error ..etc..? you can debug the javascript code

Comment: I already hit the endpoint URL in my postman and works just fine. It seems the problems lies in my axios config because it shows an error like I updated above